How can I remove unnecessary fields in the native filter Superset for example such as Previous
enter image description herethere are unnecessary fields, the user is misled, how can I remove them from the visibility field and leave only custom and last. And is there a way to add your own option from the calendar in native filters, for example DatePicker
I expect to see only last and custom in the native time range filter and nothing else.

This is not currently possible as of Superset 4.0.1.
